# How to make only one column fluid in bootstrap

Tags: layout, twitter-bootstrap-3

The following is the structure of my layout in Bootstrap 3.2:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <!-- I want this column to be fixed. -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <!-- I want only this column to be fluid. -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <!-- I want this column to be fixed. -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in psuedo-code comments, I want only the middle column to be fluid according to the screen size.

Is it possible in `container-fluid` fashion of Bootstrap? Or I should go through other ways?

Comment: So you want the side two to be a fixed width and for the middle to take up the remaining space? If so, how wide do you want the side two to be?

Comment: @ZachSaucier Suppose that it should be 250px

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no "Bootstrap way" to have columns a fixed width. So, we can use CSS to do what you want in a few ways

1. **Use flexbox** (the best way) - [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ekq0onm1/).

```
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.fixed-side-column {
  width: 250px;
}
.fluid-middle-column {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

2. Use `calc()` (or the JavaScript equivalent) keeping in mind [browser support](http://caniuse.com/calc/embed/eras=-2,) - [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/A2bOZLbWW9)

```
.row > div {
  float:left; /* Could also use display: inline-block. */
}
.fixed-side-column {
  width:250px;
}
.fluid-middle-column {
  width:calc(100% - 500px);
}
```

3. Use absolute positioning and padding on the middle element to remove the need for any calculations - [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/5LeoNY36mo)

You'd have to change the markup some

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="fluid-middle-column">
      <!-- I want only this column to be fluid. -->
    </div>
    <div class="fixed-side-column">
      <!-- I want this column to be fixed. -->
    </div>    
    <div class="fixed-side-column right">
      <!-- I want this column to be fixed. -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

/* CSS */
.fixed-side-column {
  width:250px;
  float:left;
}
.right {
  float:right;
}
.fluid-middle-column {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  padding: 0 250px 0 250px;
}
```

You'll need to add custom media queries to handle what happens when the screen is getting small.

Comment: The second fix causes problems on chrome + firefox. The z-index: -1 in the middle column means that links, controls etc in the top portion of that column are unusable.

Comment: I like [this variation of the 1st solution](http://www.bootply.com/Z1AYeFa481) that uses media queries to only apply the fixed width col on larger screens, keeping it responsive on smaller screens: http://www.bootply.com/Z1AYeFa481

Comment: I wish I could give you tons of rep!! fantastic answer.

Comment: @JamesG The answer actually didn't have the best method of going about this. The best solution is to use flexbox, which I've now added to the answer